# Remove cascade in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my collections I have a list of elements that can have one parent:

```
{id:1,
name:'name',
parent:0}

{id:2,
name:'name 2',
parent:1}

{id:3,
name:'name 3',
parent:2}

{id:4,
name:'name 4',
parent:0}
```

When I remove the object with id:1 I want to remove also items with id:2,3 also.

So I add a bind to remove on my model scheme:

**File.js**

```
schema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  this.remove({folder: this._id}).exec();
  next();
});
```

but when I remove an object I get:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I think the error is in `this.remove` which should be `File.remove`, but I'm in the file model so I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is stack overflow.

The code creates a hook on the 'remove' event which then calls, remove which triggers the remove hook again which calls remove and this repeats until your operating system cuts off your process for using too much memory.

You should implement this in a separate function which you call explicitly when you remove a parent element.

Or you could just use a relational database which are designed for relational data which is what you have. Implementing these kinds of relationships is not what mongodb was designed to do.

[Here's an article that explains when you should use nosql and when you should use a relational database](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/relational-non-relational-databases)

Comment: ok that mongodb is different from mysql but I think that 3,4 elements to remove are not so much....